# Post an xml file to an API in C# .net

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, api

I need to post an xml file to my vendor's API.
He gave me a **link, accesskey, secretkey** and told me to push xml file.
He also gave me a sample code to post XML file in json. Please find it below.

```
{
    "id": "22307a79-89dc-914e-5cf1-098f992e5054",
    "name": "Sample Request",
    "description": "",
    "order": [
        "36f699c6-0765-3e31-fdf8-863a3c3d508c"
    ],
    "folders": [],
    "timestamp": 1497005641974,
    "owner": "1189835",
    "public": false,
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "36f699c6-0765-3e31-fdf8-863a3c3d508c",
            "headers": "accessKey: 1057550\nsecretKey: t3stH11p7550\n",
            "headerData": [
                {
                    "key": "accessKey",
                    "value": "1057550",
                    "description": "",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "key": "secretKey",
                    "value": "dummy7550",
                    "description": "",
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ],
            "url": "https://feeds.vendor.com/API.php/Job/postHttpJob",
            "queryParams": [],
            "preRequestScript": null,
            "pathVariables": {},
            "pathVariableData": [],
            "method": "POST",
            "data": [
                {
                    "key": "content",
                    "value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<JobPositionPostings>\n   <JobPositionPosting>\n     <JobAction>ADD</JobAction>\n     <JobType>p</JobType>\n     <JobPositionPostingID>27</JobPositionPostingID>\n    <SummaryText>Desired Candidate Profile Summary Text - Required Competencies/Skills/Leadership E-mail\n         </SummaryText>\n         <JobExperience>\n           <MinimumExperience>2</MinimumExperience>\n           <MaximumExperience>4</MaximumExperience>\n         </JobExperience>\n         <JobQualifications>\n           <UGQualifications />\n           <UGSpecializations />\n           <PGQualifications />\n           <PGSpecializations />\n         </JobQualifications>\n       </JobPositionRequirements>\n     </JobPositionInformation>\n     <HowToApply>\n       <ApplicationMethods>\n          <ByWeb>\n           <URL>\n          </URL>\n          <ApplyIntegration>1</ApplyIntegration>\n         </ByWeb>\n       </ApplicationMethods>\n     </HowToApply>\n     </JobPositionPosting>\n</JobPositionPostings>\n",
                    "type": "text",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "key": "",
                    "value": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "type": "text",
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ],
            "dataMode": "params",
            "version": 2,
            "tests": null,
            "currentHelper": "normal",
            "helperAttributes": {},
            "time": 1501909208689,
            "name": "Sample Request",
            "description": "Sample Request with sample XML",
            "collectionId": "22307a79-89dc-914e-5cf1-098f992e5054",
            "responses": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I am working in c# .NET, how do i convert this to C# .NET or can somebody let me know how do i push an XML file to my vendor's API using C# .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: However your vendor tells you to do it. Check their API documentation or contact their support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is equivalent C# code, thank you all for the help and support. fp1 in the following code is a fileupload control.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://your-api-linkhere");
var request = new RestRequest("/api-method-here",Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("secretkey", "skey");
request.AddHeader("accesskey", "akey");
Encoding en = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string textLine = "";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fp1.FileContent);
do
{
    textLine = textLine + reader.ReadLine();
} while (reader.Peek() != -1);
reader.Close();
string requestText = string.Format("content={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textLine, en));
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", requestText, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know some people aren't going to like solution.  But you can use string.Format() method to create j

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication72
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string xml = doc.ToString();

            string json = string.Format(
                "{" +
                    "\"id\": \"22307a79-89dc-914e-5cf1-098f992e5054\"," +
                    "\"name\": \"Sample Request\"," +
                    "\"description\": \"\"," +
                    "\"order\": [" +
                        "\"36f699c6-0765-3e31-fdf8-863a3c3d508c\"" +
                    "]," +
                    "\"folders\": []," +
                    "\"timestamp\": 1497005641974," +
                    "\"owner\": \"1189835\"," +
                    "\"public\": false," +
                    "\"requests\": [" +
                        "{" +
                            "\"id\": \"36f699c6-0765-3e31-fdf8-863a3c3d508c\"," +
                            "\"headers\": \"accessKey: 1057550\nsecretKey: t3stH11p7550\n\"," +
                            "\"headerData\": [" +
                                "{" +
                                    "\"key\": \"accessKey\"," +
                                    "\"value\": \"1057550\"," +
                                    "\"description\": \"\"," +
                                    "\"enabled\": true" +
                                "}," +
                                "{" +
                                    "\"key\": \"secretKey\"," +
                                    "\"value\": \"dummy7550\"," +
                                    "\"description\": \"\"," +
                                    "\"enabled\": true" +
                                "}" +
                            "]," +
                            "\"url\": \"https://feeds.vendor.com/API.php/Job/postHttpJob\"," +
                            "\"queryParams\": []," +
                            "\"preRequestScript\": null," +
                            "\"pathVariables\": {}," +
                            "\"pathVariableData\": []," +
                            "\"method\": \"POST\"," +
                            "\"data\": [" +
                                "{" +
                                    "\"key\": \"content\"," +
                                    "\"value\": \"{0}\"," +
                                    "\"type\": \"text\"," +
                                    "\"enabled\": true" +
                                "}," +
                                "{" +
                                    "\"key\": \"\"," +
                                    "\"value\": \"\"," +
                                    "\"description\": \"\"," +
                                    "\"type\": \"text\"," +
                                    "\"enabled\": true" +
                                "}" +
                            "]," +
                            "\"dataMode\": \"params\"," +
                            "\"version\": 2," +
                            "\"tests\": null," +
                            "\"currentHelper\": \"normal\"," +
                            "\"helperAttributes\": {}," +
                            "\"time\": 1501909208689," +
                            "\"name\": \"Sample Request\"," +
                            "\"description\": \"Sample Request with sample XML\"," +
                            "\"collectionId\": \"22307a79-89dc-914e-5cf1-098f992e5054\"," +
                            "\"responses\": []" +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                "}",
                xml);

        }
    }

}
```

son like code below